# How to manage ObjectContext lifetime correctly in multi-tier application using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection

I have seen many examples using Entity Framework in MVC3 applications, they are very simple demos which only have one mvc3 web project with edmx inside it.

So, they can use the best practice for open and close connection by "using" statement:

```
using(var context = new SchoolEntities())
{
    // do some query and return View with result.
}
```

And, It can use lazy load (navigation properties) inside the "using" statment correctly, because the context is not yet 
disposed:

```
foreach(var item in student.Course)
{
    // do something with the navigation property Course
}
```

All things seems to be perfect until it becomes an n-tier application.

I created DAL, BLL, and a MVC3 UI.

The **DAL** have edmx inside it, and operator classes like **SchoolDA.cs:**

```
public class StudentDA()
{
    public Student FindStudent(int studentId)
    {
        using(var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            // do query, return a student object.
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the BLL, if I use:

```
var student = studentDa.FindStudent(103);
```

then invoke it's **navigation property**:

```
student.Course
```

I will get an error (of course):

**The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

So, I have to change StudentDA.cs like this:

```
public class StudentDA() : IDisposable
{
    private SchoolEntites context;

    public StudentDA()
    {
        context = new SchoolEntities();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

    public Student FindStudent(int studentId)
    {
        // do query, return a student object.
    }
}
```

Then, the BLL will change like this:

```
public Student FindStudent(int id)
{
    using(var studentDa = new StudentDA())
    {
        // this can access navigation properties without error, and close the connection correctly.
        return studentDa.FindStudent(id);
    }
}
```

All things seem to be perfect again until it meet Update() method.

Now, if I want to update a student object which is taken from BLL.FindStudent(), **the context.SaveChanges() will return 0, because the context is already disposed in the BLL.FindStudent()**, and nothing will be updated to database.

```
var optStudent = new StudentBO();
var student = optStudent.FindStudent(103);
student.Name = "NewValue";
optStudent.Update(student);
```

Does anyone have idea on how to use EntityFramework in 3 tire application? or how can I manage the context correctly. I will use navigation propertites very often in the web layer, but I can't always remain connection open to consume the server memory.

Comment: Search for _Inversion of Control_ and _Dependency Injection_

Comment: @Eranga also make sure you keep the scope of the context limited, .InRequestScope or .InTransientScope with ninject, this stops crosstalk and attach issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle EF context's lifetime. In web apps, usually context is unique for an HttpRequest. For example, if you want to handle this manually in a web application and have a per Thread/HttpRequest EF context, you can do so with the following (Code copied from http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management):

```
internal static class DbContextManager
{
    public static DbContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            var key = "MyDb_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x")
                      + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
            var context = HttpContext.Current.Items[key] as MyDbContext;

            if (context == null)
            {
                context = new MyDbContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = context;
            }
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can easily use:

```
var ctx = DbContextManager.Current
```

But I suggest you leave the lifetime management to an IoC framework like [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/),  [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor), or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) which automatically handle the creation/disposal of your registered obejcts along with many other features.

Comment: What difference will it make if I am using var key = "foo"; instead of that long string? Isnt var context = HttpContext.Current.Items["foo"] local to the context?

Comment: if you're just dealing of per-context lifetime management, your code is enough (clearly, easier to read as well). I have used this code which i got from Rick strahl's blog at http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management in which he talks about per context/thread lifetime management.

Comment: It seems elegant, because you use `Current` it seems that session is cleaned at end of request. Thanks, testing it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Kamyar. I came across this whilst looking for a simple strategy to manage the ObjectContext lifetime without having to use an IoC framework, which seems a bit overkill for my needs.

I also came across your other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947397/3099615), for disposing of the context at the end of the request.

Thought this might be useful for others coming across this, so just posting my implementation of your code here:

Context manager class -

```
internal static class MyDBContextManager
    {
        //Unique context key per request and thread
        private static string Key
        {
            get
            { 
                return string.Format("MyDb_{0}{1}", arg0: HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x"),
                    arg1: Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID);
            }
        }

        //Get and set request context
        private static MyDBContext Context
        {
            get { return HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] as MyDBContext; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] = value; }
        }

        //Context per request
        public static MyDBContext Current
        {
            get
            {
                //if null, create new context 
                if (Context == null)
                {
                    Context = new MyDBContext();
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[Key] = Context;
                }
                return Context;
            }
        }

        //Dispose any created context at the end of a request - called from Global.asax
        public static void Dispose()
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
            }
    }
}
```

Global.asax (MVC) -

```
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        EndRequest +=MvcApplication_EndRequest; 
    }

    private void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDBContextManager.Dispose();
    }
```