# TransactionScope in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, transactionscope

I have an MVC 4 application, and while registering I have come across issue where data is saved in usertable but not in other table i.e user_detail etc.., to avoid that I tried to use tranascationScope well it worked for the registemethod as below.

```
 public ActionResult Register(model model)
 {
     using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
         WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.RegUserName, randomPassword,....)
         // other table commit.
         // other table commit.
     }
 }
```

Once after register a call is being made to any action method as below

```
 private void AuthenticateUser(string userName)
 {
      int userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(userName);
 }
```

**The current TransactionScope is already complete.**

I am getting the above error and the connection is a single and using EF5.

Comment: you should indent your code for make it more readable...

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  What is the *actual* code you're using?  I can assure you that your *comments* aren't generating errors, but the actual code you're not showing us very well could be.

Comment: Show us your code where you initialize the DBContext, I have a feeling your reusing the same instance for every db call.

Comment: Well I am using structure Map .NET IoC containers and for everytable there is a separate object and the same is being used for all actions in the controller for every db operation. Just wanted to know If this doable or I should take any other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on StructureMap, but from the error I guess, you're creating a single instance (Singleton) from the DBContext. which will give you this error.

Once you start a transaction, the context will be aware of it and handle your work, but after the transaction is complete you can't resuse the same dbcontext instance, you need to create a new one.

A preferred method in web apps is to use a Context Per Request. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543894/entity-framework-object-context-per-request-in-asp-net) I found on SO.