# Managing DbContext EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm building a Webforms EF6 database first application and am not sure how best to manage DbContext. I looked at a lot of tutorials and forum posts but I'm still sure. Regarding the much favored 'using per request', I've not found a way to save parent & children in one go. I got it to work with the code below, but where and when would I dispose of the context? Can I use this approach? Would the per request approach by Kamyar [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543894/entity-framework-object-context-per-request-in-asp-net) be better?

Here's what I've got now:

```
public static class ContextManager
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static MyContext current;

    public static MyContext MyCurrentContext
    {
        get{
        if (current == null)
            current = new MyContext();

        return current;
    }}
}
```

coupled with

```
var context = ContextManager.MyCurrentContext;
.....
context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

A specific example would be 'UserProfile' which contains child objects as properties such as  'DefaultInvoiceAddress' which returns the user's default invoice address from a table with all the user's addresses. In the last web application I worked on, when user edits this address from within the profile (e.g. street change), together with other profile information from other tables, EF would save all edited information from the different tables in one request (ensuring they're attached). Since I wasn't privy to the context management, I don't know how it was done, but we would always assign a common current context for the requests.

I came across [this post by Rick Strahl](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management), and [this one by Jordan van Gogh](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx) - the business object / transaction seem to be an answer, but I don't quite understand how to implement it and couldn't find an example. The 'shared ObjectContext instance per HTTP request' corresponds to Kamyar's answer mentioned above, and all things considered, it sounds a good option. Would I have to explicitly dispose of the context, if so when/where?. Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'save parent & children in one go'? Preferably with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea. Static is totally against the best practices. No 2 users ever will use the app at the same time? Ouch. For WebForms.

Per request IS the best choice.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate what you're saying, but then how to benefit from change tracking and implement parent/child save in one block? it gives a 'not from the same context' error when I try to attach a child

Comment: @devlock maybe you could edit your question and give us a more specific example of the usage scenario you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The EF db context object is **not**, I repeat **NOT** threadsafe no matter how you manage it. Lots of problems can arise from sharing a db context across threads so the best way is, as mentioned above to use it per request.

If you don't want to jump into the IoC/DI side of things a really simple way to do it is whenever you need the database you just instantiate your context in a `using` block, like so:

```
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    // code reading from/writing to database
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, I added a comment above which applies to your answer, too

Answer (score 0):

Using singleton pattern with entity framework database context is a design defect specially if you work with concurrency environment such as web forms because you have to take in your consideration that DbContext is not thread safe object.