# Having static Repository class in a webforms project reuses entity framework connections?

Tags: entity-framework, webforms

I have a

```
public static class Repository
```

in my webforms project.

In the static block of that class I setup my entity framework entity object:

```
private static readonly ProjectEntities db;
static Repository()
{
  db = new ProjectEntities("Name=ProjectEntities");
}
```

Then I setup some public static methods like this:

```
public static Order GetOrder(int orderID)
{
  return db.Orders.First(o => o.OrderID == orderID);
}
```

The problem is that when for instance deletions fails (because of some constraint), I randomly gets some clues about that in subsequent connections, coming up as exceptions as a result of queries that should be innocent. For instance, exceptions about deletions as a result of select queries.

I never

```
db.AcceptAllChanges();
```

upon any exception, and I should not have to, because across page accesses, there should be no trace of failed queries. Or should it? Is the cleaning responsibility on me?

Those problems should not be because of me using static (please say it is not like that), so is it related to entity framework connection pooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the entity framework context is meant to be short lived - i.e. it is generally regarded as a unit of work whereby you create it for a particular task and dispose of it at the end. It's a light weight object, and should be used in this way.

You issue is as a result of the object being long lived (i.e. in a singleton shared across requests). In this case the internal state of the context is becoming invalid - i.e. you try to delete something, it cannot persist those changes to the database, and is therefore in an invalid state.

You could probably resolve your issue by calling the refresh method before making use of the object in every case - this will cause the object to update its state based on the database - but this will probably cause other issues.

However, this is the wrong thing to do - the context should be created, used and disposed per request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not expect the lifetime of the object being across requests, why would it be that?

Comment: A single asp.net process can serve multiple web requests - therefore a static class (which is scoped to the AppDomain i.e. the process) will be shared across multiple requests. In IIS it is possible that you could have multiple processes - but you should not make any assumptions based on this.

Comment: Yes - one process can be multi threaded and iis will use thread pools to service the request.

Comment: Meaning that my static variables can be accessed simultaneously then

Comment: Yes definitely - your static variables might be accessible simultaneously, but as I said before, you cannot guarantee anything. IIS might be running 2 processes, and could in theory send any request to any process.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously suggest you investigate the lifecycle management of your context object.
Have a look at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945715/how-to-manage-objectcontext-lifetime-correctly-in-multi-tier-application-using-e/11947397#11947397) as to what your options are.